# Unable to load OpenNLP sentence model in Hadoop map-reduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, opennlp

I'm trying to get OpenNLP integrated into a map-reduce job on Hadoop, starting with some basic sentence splitting. Within the map function, the following code is run:

```
public AnalysisFile analyze(String content) {
    InputStream modelIn = null;
    String[] sentences = null;

    // references an absolute path to en-sent.bin
    logger.info("sentenceModelPath: " + sentenceModelPath);

    try {
        modelIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream(sentenceModelPath);
        SentenceModel model = new SentenceModel(modelIn);
        SentenceDetectorME sentenceBreaker = new SentenceDetectorME(model);
        sentences = sentenceBreaker.sentDetect(content);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("Unable to locate sentence model.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (modelIn != null) {
            try {
                modelIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    logger.info("number of sentences: " + sentences.length);

    <snip>
}
```

When I run my job, I'm getting an error in the log saying "in must not be null!" [(source of class throwing error)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.opennlp/opennlp-tools/1.5.2-incubating/opennlp/tools/util/model/BaseModel.java), which means that somehow I can't open an InputStream to the model. Other tidbits:

- I've verified that the model file exists in the location `sentenceModelPath` refers to.
- I've added Maven dependencies for opennlp-maxent:3.0.2-incubating, opennlp-tools:1.5.2-incubating, and opennlp-uima:1.5.2-incubating.
- Hadoop is just running on my local machine.

Most of this is boilerplate from the [OpenNLP documentation](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect.detection.api). Is there something I'm missing, either on the Hadoop side or the OpenNLP side, that would cause me to be unable to read from the model?

Comment: What's the value of `sentenceModelPath` (what does the logger info statement print?). Is this path on the local file system, in the job jar, or in HDFS somewhere?

Comment: @ChrisWhite I've got it set to a path in HDFS (`/sandbox/corpus-analysis/nlp/en-sent.bin`) and also tested it with a path on the local file system (a la `/home/cyranix/path/to/en-sent.bin`). No dice with either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the `getClass().getResourceAsStream(sentenceModelPath)` line. This will try to load a file from the classpath - neither the file in HDFS nor on the client local file system is part of the classpath at mapper / reducer runtime, so this is why you're seeing the Null error (the getResourceAsStream() returns null if the resource cannot be found).

To get around this you have a number of options:

- Amend your code to load the file from HDFS:

> ```
> modelIn = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration()).open(
>                  new Path("/sandbox/corpus-analysis/nlp/en-sent.bin"));
> ```

Amend your code to load the file from the local dir, and use the `-files` GenericOptionsParser option (which copies to file from the local file system to HDFS, and back down to the local directory of the running mapper / reducer):

> ```
> modelIn = new FileInputStream("en-sent.bin");
> ```

Hard-bake the file into the job jar (in the root dir of the jar), and amend your code to include a leading slash:

> ```
> modelIn = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/en-sent.bin");</li>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Still getting familiar with Hadoop. Since our project may end up including distinct trained models, the `-files` option will probably work best (and I got it to load successfully this morning), but loading from HDFS may be handy in other areas.