# Sentence detection using opennlp on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, detection, opennlp, sentence

I want to do sentence detection using OPenNLP and Hadoop. I have implemented same on Java successfully. Want to implement same on Mapreduce platform. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this two different ways.
One way is to push out your Sentence detection model to each node to a standard dir (ie /opt/opennlpmodels/), and at the class level in your mapper class read in the serialized model, and then use it appropriately in your map or reduce function.

Another way is to put the model in a database or the distributed cache (as a blob or something... I have used Accumulo to store Document categorization models before like this). then at the class level make the connection to the database and get the model as a bytearrayinputstream.

I have used Puppet to push out the models, but use whatever you typically use to keep files up to date on your cluster.

depending on your hadoop version you may be able to sneak the model in as a property on jobsetup and then only the master (or wherever you launch jobs from) will need to have the actual model file on it. I've never tried this.

If you need to know how to actually use the OpenNLP sentence detector let me know and I'll post an example.
HTH

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetector;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel;
import opennlp.tools.util.Span;

public class SentenceDetection {

  SentenceDetector sd;

  public Span[] getSentences(String docTextFromMapFunction) throws Exception {

    if (sd == null) {
      sd = new SentenceDetectorME(new SentenceModel(new FileInputStream(new File("/standardized-on-each-node/path/to/en-sent.zip"))));
    }
    /**
     * this gives you the actual sentences as a string array
     */
    // String[] sentences = sd.sentDetect(docTextFromMapFunction);
    /**
     * this gives you the spans (the charindexes to the start and end of each
     * sentence in the doc)
     *
     */
    Span[] sentenceSpans = sd.sentPosDetect(docTextFromMapFunction);
    /**
     * you can do this as well to get the actual sentence strings based on the spans
     */
    // String[] spansToStrings = Span.spansToStrings(sentPosDetect, docTextFromMapFunction);
    return sentenceSpans;
  }
}
```

HTH... just make sure the file is in place. There are more elegant ways of doing this but this works and it's simple.

Comment: this might help as well

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592147/unable-to-load-opennlp-sentence-model-in-hadoop-map-reduce-job?rq=1

Comment: Hi, that would be great help in understanding if you could able to site some example.